# how to avoid rebuilding duplicate widgets when navigating back to previous page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

When the user logs in, they get pushed to the homepage and their data is retrieved from database on initstate and then the widgets are built. However, i noticed for the widgets that are built without a streambuilder, where i manually retrieve data once, are duplicated if i navigate to another page and then come back. When I say duplicated I mean the exact same data is redundantly copied again using the same widget, so like a users' profile pic could show up twice. I am using a listview most of the time for these cases/

How do i avoid this and just built the widgets once so if the user goes back the page stays the same?

Comment: well, you cannot do that

Comment: You have to declare variable of Widget type and define it in initState method. and set this variable as child of your parent widget.

Comment: @iPatel Could you provide an example or elaborate i'm not sure how i would set this widget variable in initstate as the child of a parent widget. Also its not just one widget thats being duplicated its many dynamic widgets so how would that work?

Comment: you cannot do that - the `build()` method will always be executed

Comment: Show us your problem code. What you are describing is the issue with your code. As @pskink said, build() is always called. What you are doing is, pushing same code in a singleton or something which is causing redundant data.